# Why is this JavaScript parameter getting lost?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api

In this function, the value parameter is being passed down to fill in my URL. This works perfectly.

```
function showResults(results) {
  var html = '';
  $.each(results, function(index,value) {
    html += '<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' +     value.id.videoId + '" class="html5lightbox"><img src="' +     value.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url + '">' + value.snippet.title +    '(</a>More from <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/' +     value.snippet.channelId + '">' + value.snippet.channelTitle + '</a>)</li>';
  });
  $('#results').html(html);
}
```

In this nearly identical function, the value param loses its value. I can't see how. It's difficult to debug why this is happening because console.log() just returns "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" no matter what I check (it returns this in the first section too, which works well).

```
function showResults(results) {
  var html = '';
  $.each(results, function(index,value) {
    html += '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + value.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url +  '">' + value.snippet.title + '</a>) </li>';
  });
  $('#results').html(html);

  $('#results li a').click(function(){
    playVid($(this).attr(value.id.videoId));
  });
}

function playVid(vidID) {
  var embedVid = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+vidID+'?autoplay=1';
  document.getElementById('player').src = embedVid;
}
```

Here I'm trying to push the value param (in the url again) to an iframe with id="player". The iframe receives an invalid param and the video won't play. Meanwhile the video plays in the first example. Where does value get lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` only exists within the scope of the `each` loop. So, first fix your reference error, and then I suggest the following changes in that second example:

1) Update the `href` with the `videoId` value in the `each` loop like in the first example:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + value.id.videoId + '">
```

2) And then launch the player with that value:

```
$('#results li a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  playVid($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: I don't understand. The anchor does not have value.id.videoId

Comment: Updated. Do my changes make more sense?

Comment: Why did it work when we passed href version, but not the item itself? I tried passing it as a variable, as a global variable, as itself, but no dice. Why as href? Whats so special about those anchor tags?

Comment: As I said, `value` doesn't exist outside of `each` so we need to attach that information to the element in the loop. It didn't have to be `href` - I could have used a data attribute, but `href` made sense particularly in light of the first example.